# Angular not recognizinig type of object

Tags: java, angular, typescript, typechecking

I have an angular project with a java backend.

the following is the scenario.

I create a DTO object in the Backend, and submit it to the frontend.

```
    ...
    QuestionResponseDTO dto = new QuestionResponseDTO();
    dto.setStart(ZonedDateTime.now());
    dto.setEnd(ZonedDateTime.now());
    dto.setDuration("X seconds");
    dto.setResponse(new ActivityListResponseDTO(Arrays.asList("Cooking", "Eating")));
    return dto;
}
```

in which the ActivityListResponseDTO just contains a `List<String> activities`.
Also note that ActivityListResponseDTO extends QuestionResponseBodyDTO.

In the frontend I send the request to the backend, and I receive the object back.
this is how the object looks like.

```
{"id":2,"responses":[{"id":0,"dto":{"start":"2021-06-16T09:08:28.142Z","end":"2021-06-16T09:08:28.142Z","duration":"X seconds",
"response":{
"activities":["Cooking","Eating"],
"typeName":"ActivityListResponseDTO",
"className":null},
"typeName":"QuestionResponseDTO",
"className":null}}]}
```

which means that the backend works fine.

The java classes I mentioned earlier have their corresponding classes in the Frontend with the exact same name. Idk what exactly happens to parse the response.

When I receive the object I check:

```
//angular
if (dto instanceof QuestionResponseDTO) {
        console.log("this ran");
        const responseBody = ((<QuestionResponseDTO>dto).response);

        if(responseBody instanceof ActivityListResponseDTO) {
          console.log("this ran 2");
          // because backend only returns a string
          const arr = (<ActivityListResponseDTO>responseBody)
            .activities.map(s => ({stringContent: s}));
...
```

The `responseBody` per default has the Type QuestionResponseBodyDTO in the frontend as well. the ActivityListResponseDTO extends this in the frontend too, so it should work.
but for some reason the program doesn't go in the inner if statement, and `"this ran 2"` is never logged.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the frontend http service?

Comment: Even if you have a `QuestionResponseDTO` class defined in your frontend, what you are getting from the backend is not an instance of that class. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: @tmsbrndz i'm kinda legally not allowed to, had to sign an NDA. Also I don't really have access to it. Not sure how the workflow is. Don't have access to all the code.

Answer (score 0):

The response received from the HTTP API will be a simple JSON Object.

For it to work correctly on frontend, you will have to map that object to its corresponding type on frontend.

You can use [json-object-mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-object-mapper) library to achieve this.

1. Create a Typescript class named QuestionResponseDTO with all the nested object classes. I usually do this using [json2ts](http://json2ts.com/) which provides me interfaces and then I convert those interfaces to typescript classes.
2. Use json-object-mapper or use your own class constructors to initialize the properties
3. In your HTTP service, when you get the data, pipe that data to deserialize it to typescript object. `http.get<QuestionResponseDTO>(url).pipe(map(data => ObjectMapper.deserialize(QuestionResponseDTO, data)));`
4. Once this is done, you should be able to correctly use `instanceof` on any nested objects